# InvalidOperationException - The type ITenant does not have an accessible constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am new to unity dependency injection, and I'm using mvc and DI in my project. I used an interface ICUS and then created one class that is implements it.

When I resolve this class, I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException - The type iCUS does not have an accessible
>   constructor Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "GG.Framework.Configuration.iCUS ", name = "(none)". Exception
>   occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type iCUS does not have an accessible
>   constructor.
>   At the time of the exception, the container was: Resolving
>   GG.Framework.Configuration.iCUS, (none)

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Post class, interface, and registration code.

Comment: it is resolved by removing duplicate mapping of unity configuration in the unity config file, thx for your reply.